# How to implement a wait function inside my onSensorChanged method

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop

What I want:

Once a value is reached on the sensor, the program should wait for some seconds, and then go into a while loop that is true until a certain sensor value is reached. Once out the while loop the rest of the code continues processing and storing values into some sql database.

What I've tried:

Threads, Handlers, and Runnables ... too many attempts to post the code.

My Problem:

the while loop iterations. It always runs just 1 time.

Results:

Nothing close to my desired resul

Comment: Why not use `Thread.sleep(1000)`?

Comment: That's not the issue i'm facing now. I have used time.sleep twice in my process... once for the if statement (which is a runnable) and once inside the while loop ... the while loop is just another runnable called from the other runnable. The while loop runnable calls itself over and over again until another value is reached... but now I cant get the while loop to close ... it just runs forever.

Comment: I did this because after 20 attempts I figured its best to put all my code that i want to run after if statement into the main runnable now since that was the closest attempt I had to my desired goal. However, that was a few attempts ago and I have forgotten how the code looked. My recreation attempt has resulted in a slow UI with a while loop that doesn't end

Answer (score 0):

You can force the executing thread to sleep for some amount of milliseconds. For example:

```
//Condition to sleep occurs
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    //log
}
```

This will cause the thread to sleep for 3 seconds before continuing with execution (unless interrupted). Threads are a powerful thing to know in Java. I'd start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

The concurrency lesson in the Javadocs is fantastic, in my opinion.